# Calculating the difference between first and last row in each group

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe containing date, price, and a binary group (1/0 for discount or not discount) as show in the picture:

[image: sample]

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(16437, 16440, 16441, 16442,16443, 16444, 16447, 16448, 16449, 16450, 16451, 16454, 16455, 16456, 16457, 16458, 16461, 16462, 16463, 16464), class = "Date"),     price = c(7.859, 7.964, 7.942, 8.117, 8.066, 7.918, 7.856,     7.82, 7.828, 7.791, 7.785, 7.789, 7.446, 7.401, 7.37, 7.283,     7.299, 7.25, 7.228, 7.219), discount = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,     0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

A discount group represents individual period which has various lengths of days (it can be thought as discount week).

I would like to calculate the difference between first and last price in each group of discount.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Post the output of `dput(your_data)` into your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming `dplyr`.) *Not* assuming that `date` is guaranteed to be in order; if it is, then one could also use `first(.)`/`last(.)` for the same results. I tend to prefer not trusting order ...)

If your `discount` is always 0/1 and you are looking to group by contiguous same-values, then

```r
dat %>%
  group_by(discountgrp = cumsum(discount != lag(discount, default = discount[1]))) %>%
  summarize(change = price[which.max(date)] - price[which.min(date)])
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   discountgrp change
#         <int>  <dbl>
# 1           0 -0.871
# 2           1 -0.481
```

If your `discount` is instead a categorical value and can exceed 1, then

```r
dat %>%
  group_by(discount) %>%
  summarize(change = price[which.max(date)] - price[which.min(date)])
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   discount change
#      <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1        0 -0.871
# 2        1 -0.481
```

They happen to be the same here, but if the row order were changed such that some of the `1`s occurred in the middle of `0`s (for instance), then the groups would be different.

Original data, before OP changed it:

```r
dat <- structure(list(date = structure(c(16443, 16444, 16447, 16448, 16449, 16457, 16458, 16461, 16462, 16463, 16464, 16465, 16468, 16469, 16470, 16471, 16472, 16475, 16476, 16484, 16437, 16440, 16441, 16442, 16450, 16451, 16454, 16455, 16456, 16477, 16478, 16479, 16482, 16483, 16492, 16493, 16496, 16497, 16498, 16520), class = "Date"), price = c(8.066, 7.918, 7.856, 7.82, 7.828, 7.37, 7.283, 7.299, 7.25, 7.228, 7.219, 7.168, 7.118, 7.031, 7.098, 7.11, 7.156, 7.189, 7.195, 7.195, 7.859, 7.964, 7.942, 8.117,  7.791, 7.785, 7.789, 7.446, 7.401, 7.412, 7.529, 7.495, 7.456, 7.393, 7.104, 7.062, 7.081, 7.115, 7.289, 7.378), discount = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -40L), groups = structure(list(discount = c(0, 1), .rows = structure(list(1:20, 21:40), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

New data:

```r
dat <- structure(list(date = structure(c(16437, 16440, 16441, 16442,16443, 16444, 16447, 16448, 16449, 16450, 16451, 16454, 16455, 16456, 16457, 16458, 16461, 16462, 16463, 16464), class = "Date"),     price = c(7.859, 7.964, 7.942, 8.117, 8.066, 7.918, 7.856,     7.82, 7.828, 7.791, 7.785, 7.789, 7.446, 7.401, 7.37, 7.283,     7.299, 7.25, 7.228, 7.219), discount = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,     0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

With this updated data:

```r
dat %>%
  group_by(discountgrp = cumsum(discount != lag(discount, default = discount[1]))) %>%
  summarize(change = price[which.max(date)] - price[which.min(date)])
# # A tibble: 4 × 2
#   discountgrp change
#         <int>  <dbl>
# 1           0  0.258
# 2           1 -0.238
# 3           2 -0.390
# 4           3 -0.151
```

and the second block, new data:

```r
dat %>%
  group_by(discount) %>%
  summarize(change = price[which.max(date)] - price[which.min(date)])
# # A tibble: 2 × 2
#   discount change
#      <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1        0 -0.847
# 2        1 -0.458
```

A recent add to `dplyr_1.1.0` (and newer) is `dplyr::consecutive_id()`, which may be useful here.

```r
dat %>%
  group_by(discountgrp = consecutive_id(discount)) %>%
  summarize(change = price[which.max(date)] - price[which.min(date)])
```

Comment: Hi @r2evans, yes this works! In my case, the discount is always 0/1, so I use your first solution. Thanks alot!

Comment: Maybe update your solution with `dplyr::consecutive_id()`.

Answer (score 1):

Using *data.table*:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(x)[order(grp, date), .(priceDiff = head(price, 1) - tail(price, 1)), 
         by = (grp = rleid(discount)) ]
#    grp priceDiff
# 1:   1    -0.258
# 2:   2     0.238
# 3:   3     0.390
# 4:   4     0.151
```

Comment: Hi zx8754, yes this data.table approach works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

One way would be the following:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(discount, date) %>% 
  group_by(discount) %>% 
  summarise(diff = first(price) - last(price))

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
# discount  diff
# <dbl> <dbl>
# 1        0 0.871
# 2        1 0.481
```

You can replace `summarise(diff = first(price) - last(price))` with `summarise(diff = head(price, 1) - tail(price, 1))`, which will generate the same output.

Comment: Hi AlexB,  thanks for the solution but I'd like to calculate for each period. I think i made mistake in providing the code thus the date is not in correct order, sory for that. I just corrected the dataset code.

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution

sort the dataframe, just to be sure

```
df=df[order(df$date),]
```

create a new variable for grouping

```
df["grp"]=cumsum(df["discount"]!=rbind(-1,head(df["discount"],-1)))
```

aggregate and difference

```
aggregate(
  price~grp,
  df,
  function(x){head(x,1)-tail(x,1)}
)

  grp  price
1   1 -0.258
2   2  0.238
3   3  0.390
4   4  0.175
5   5  0.019
6   6  0.000
7   7 -0.274
```

Comment: Hi, yes this works! Thanks a lot! The difference with solution from @r2evans is your code use (head - tail) not (tail - head), but that doesn't matter. You are correct that the date should be in order (sory i made mistake when providing sample code for dataset).

Comment: Could you explain what rbind(-1,head(df["discount"],-1) does here?

Comment: @vegatroz that part just shifts the discount values by 1, so lag 1, and then adds an arbitrary number at the beginning to pad the missing value.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tapply`.

```
res <- with(DF, tapply(price, list(week=I(cumsum(c(0, diff(discount)) != 0) + 1)), 
                       \(x) x[length(x)] - x[1]))
res
# week
#      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10 
# -0.246 -0.529 -0.082 -0.008  0.039  0.258 -0.345  0.094 -0.394  0.297
```

Or `ave`.

```
DF <- transform(DF, d=ave(price, cumsum(c(0, diff(discount)) != 0), 
                          FUN=\(x) x[length(x)] - x[1]))
DF
#          date price discount      d
# 1  2015-01-08 8.066        0 -0.246
# 2  2015-01-09 7.918        0 -0.246
# 3  2015-01-12 7.856        0 -0.246
# 4  2015-01-13 7.820        0 -0.246
# 5  2015-01-14 7.828        1 -0.529
# 6  2015-01-22 7.370        1 -0.529
# 7  2015-01-23 7.283        1 -0.529
# 8  2015-01-26 7.299        1 -0.529
# 9  2015-01-27 7.250        0 -0.082
```

---

*Data*

```
DF <- structure(list(date = structure(c(16443, 16444, 16447, 16448, 
16449, 16457, 16458, 16461, 16462, 16463, 16464, 16465, 16468, 
16469, 16470, 16471, 16472, 16475, 16476, 16484, 16437, 16440, 
16441, 16442, 16450, 16451, 16454, 16455, 16456, 16477, 16478, 
16479, 16482, 16483, 16492, 16493, 16496, 16497, 16498, 16520
), class = "Date"), price = c(8.066, 7.918, 7.856, 7.82, 7.828, 
7.37, 7.283, 7.299, 7.25, 7.228, 7.219, 7.168, 7.118, 7.031, 
7.098, 7.11, 7.156, 7.189, 7.195, 7.195, 7.859, 7.964, 7.942, 
8.117, 7.791, 7.785, 7.789, 7.446, 7.401, 7.412, 7.529, 7.495, 
7.456, 7.393, 7.104, 7.062, 7.081, 7.115, 7.289, 7.378), discount = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi @jay.sf, thanks for the solution, however when I copy your code to my Rstudio it shows error:  
"unexpected input in:
"transform(cek, d=ave(price, cumsum(c(0, diff(discount)) != 0), 
                          FUN=\"

Comment: @vegatroz Just abbreviated function notation, available since R4.1. Replace `\(x)` with `function(x)` and it should work. Or even better: [update your R](https://www.r-project.org/).